# Service to add HTTPS to an API without my own SSL certificate or domain

Tags: security, ssl, https, dns, ssl-certificate

I have an api served at a hypothetical address http://82.12.61.115:8000 (note the port).

I want to have a domain point at that IP address and then secure that domain with an SSL certificate.

Is there any service I can use (e.g. AWS) to do this without buying the domain and SSL certificate? Since it is just an API, it doesn't have to be pretty, it can be a subdomain of another domain as long as it's secured.

On a related note, will using port 8000 be a problem (as opposed to 80 or 443)?

Comment: Different port should not be an issue, but TLS for an IP address may be tricky. Check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/193775/ssl-certificate-for-a-public-ip-address

Comment: You can have certificates on IP address, it works technically, but this is almost always not the solution for whatever problem you have. As said "it can be a subdomain of another domain as long as it's secured." so use that as name in the URL instead of an IP, and you are back to "normal" name based certificates.

Comment: That's a good idea, although ideally I'd like a service that does this for me.

Comment: E.g. It gives me a domain like 82-12-61-115-endpoint.service.com that directs to  82.12.61.115 and it's already HTTPS secured for port 8000

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use AWS API Gateway as a proxy service. It will give you a domain name with SSL. Check [this](https://codethief.io/aws-connect-api-gateway-to-ec2/) guide. Please remember that this won't add SSL to your API instance, end of the day communication between your API and API gateway will be unsecured. But you will get a nice URL that you can call from the frontend.